# Animate fadeIn issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am attempting to run a `fadeIn()` and `animate()` function to have the `contact-arrow-fade-container` **fade** and **animate** in from the right side and then fall into place in its parent div `contact-arrow-content-wrap`'s position at **13%**.
 For some reason I am not even getting this to display. I have it set at `display: none`, but shouldn't the `fadeIn` allow this to show?

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
function fade(){
 $('#contact-arrow-fade-container').fadeIn(500);
 $('#contact-arrow-fade-container').animate({'left': '0%'}, 700);
};
```

```css
#contact-arrow-content-wrap {
 margin: 30% 13% 5% 13%;
}
#contact-arrow-fade-container {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 left: 80%;
}
#contact-box-title1 {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2em;
}
#contact-box-title2 {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 4.8em;
 padding-top: 25px;
}
#contact-box-description {
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact-arrow-content-wrap">
  <div id="contact-arrow-fade-container">
    <div id="contact-box-title1">REACH OUT AND</div>
    <div id="contact-box-title2">SAY HELLO</div>
    <div id="contact-box-description">Have questions, comments, or just want to say hello?
 Feel free to start the dialogue; we look forward to stimulating conversations. For project
 inquiries kindly visit <span id="contact-link"><a href="discuss-project">Discuss a Project</a></span>.</div>
 <div id="contact-box-call-container">
  <div id="contact-box-call-title">Need to speak with someone? Call us!</div>
  <div id="contact-box-call-title">(555) 555-5555</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: who is calling `fade()` method

Comment: You need to have a script like `jQuery(function($){fade()});` or just `jQuery(fade)`

Comment: He means how the `fade()` function is being fired/called? upon an event, or automatically?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pL4n6ybo/1/

Comment: Gotchaaaa... it seems my `fadeIn` takes place and then my `animate`. Is there anyway to get this to work simultaneously?

Comment: by simultaneously you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/pL4n6ybo/3/ ?

Comment: Yes. Perfect! Thanks! I will accept an answer, you both helped a lot and Mi-creativity, I am actually using your method you posted earlier, without the function name to reduce the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `.#contact-arrow-fade-container` rule :

```
opacity: 0;
```

Change your jQuery code to this:

```
(function() {
    $('#contact-arrow-fade-container').animate({
        'opacity' : 1, 'left': 0
    }, 700);
})();
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pL4n6ybo/3/)